# Bind a windows minimum Height and minimum Width to pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

so here is the set up. I have a frame inside a window that holds all my pages. As I navigate through pages I want to be able to bind my **window's** minimum width and minimum height based off what **page** I am on. So basically I want the windows min width and min height to be based off each pages min width and min height.

Here is my frame

```
<Window x:Class="Project_Tracking.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Title="Project Tracking"
    Icon="/Images/AlarmClock.ico"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="/Views/LoginView.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden">

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

I am using MVVM light for this application. I am looking for a suggestion that uses no code behind. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you set an explicit min height and width for the pages or what height and width do you want to use?

Comment: I do set an explicit min width and height for the pages. I am honestly open to any suggestions on how to do it. I am looking for the best solution. @mm8

Comment: Did you try setting the SizeToContent property of the window to WidthAndHeight?

Comment: Yes I tried that, It doesn't apply to minimums though.

Comment: What minimums...? You haven't included any sample code that proves your point. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When I use SizeToContent property it DOES size to the content of the page but the minimum height and width of the window is still the default value, even if I set the minimum height and width in the page. I literally have no code yet for this I am simply looking for a solution to the question.

Comment: You need to write some code that sets the MinHeight and MinWidth properties of the window. Or disable resizing it. Of course this code belongs to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties of the content of the frame:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    MinWidth="{Binding Content.MinWidth, ElementName=mainFrame}"
    MinHeight="{Binding Content.MinHeight, ElementName=mainFrame}"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Source="Views/LoginView.xaml">

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

It seems to work on my example with a single page.